# Facebook Browser on iPhone & Android doesn't submit the form on my website

Tags: android, ios, iphone, wordpress, facebook

I have a website that works fine on desktop and mobile.

Basically you need to submit a form with an image.

Only problem is that it doesn't work properly when opened through the mobile browser for Facebook on iPhone and Android.

My website is made using Wordpress and the form is through Ninja Forms.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Could you add a minimum runnable sample of the form?

Comment: See if you can get some of the errors. You can remote debug android chrome https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging. You could also create an emulator in XCode if you have a mac.

Comment: Can you at least provide your URL?

Comment: Hi All, thanks for the help so far. Still can't seem to fix this though. 

URL: http://www.jetchef.co.za

Answer (score 0):

I realize this answer is over a year late for the OP, but someone else might find it useful.

If you're using Ninja Forms Ajax Submit, and your Ajax code requires cookies, you're out of luck because the Facebook In-App Browser doesn't send cookies for post-page-load Ajax. I don't know if there's a workaround; maybe ask the Ninja Forms creators.